# Extracting the indices of points within a polygon in a scatterplot in python?

Tags: python, scatter-plot

In Mathematica, I could extract the indices of the points in the scatter plot using the code given here

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/478643.

```
points = RandomSample[
   Transpose[{Flatten[{RandomReal[{0, 5}, 20], RandomReal[{4, 4.5}, 10]}], 
 Flatten[{RandomReal[1, 20], RandomReal[{1.5, 2}, 10]}]}], 30];

winding[poly_, pt_] := Round[(Total @ Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@
  (ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)]

DynamicModule[{pl, pos},
 pl = SmoothDensityHistogram[points, ColorFunction -> 
"TemperatureMap"];
 Manipulate[
  pos = Pick[Range[Length[points]], Unitize[winding[poly, #] & /@ 
points], 1];
  Show[pl, 
   Epilog -> {{Darker[Green], PointSize[Medium], 
Point[points[[pos]]]},
 {Black, Point[Complement[points, points[[pos]]]]},
 {EdgeForm[{Red, Dashed}], FaceForm[], Polygon[poly]}}],

  {{poly, {}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> All},
  Row[{Button["Copy Points", Print[pos]], Button["Reset", poly = {}; pos = {}]}]]]
```

[image]

I am trying to achieve the same in Jupyterlab using python. As I am still a beginner I do not how to pursue this problem in python.

Comment: Please provide code examples as text in your question not as a link. Your own efforts are expected to be included.

Comment: As Michael said, essential information is missing in your question. How do you create your scatter plot (??? - your example shows a contour plot), which libraries do you use, what would be the expected output?